# Installing ubuntu 12.10 on a laptop with windows 8 pre installed, such that bootloader of windows 8 is used

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

How do I install Ubuntu 12.10 on a laptop with windows 8 pre-installed, such that the bootloader of windows 8 is used everytime the laptop boots.

Comment: I don't think that is quite possible right now, There's been a lot of question about dual booting Windows  8 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *EasyBCD* for using the Widnows bootloader.

Run it from inside Windows, and you can make the desired changes.